# FOREACH LOOPS calls and print problems

Tags: c#, foreach

In the following code, I'm curious as to why the final foreach loop prints out the "Alert" writeline three times.For example itll print 
message 1
message 2
message 3
message 1
message 2
message 3
Also it only calls the last Pop..Pop is a pop up notification that displays the type of message from the javascript side..There are exactly 3 messages being sent but the notification only appears with the last messages text.

Oh and "i" always prints 0, it never increments.

```
     NameValueCollection NV = new NameValueCollection();
        NV.Add("TOKEN", EncodeTo64(EncodeTo64(uid)));
        string[] values = null;
        string post = HttpPost("https:somewebsite.com", NV);
        foreach (string k in NV.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ONE");
            values = NV.GetValues(k);
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TWO");
                var mm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Messages>>(DecodeFrom64(post));
                foreach (Messages m1 in mm)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("THREE\n");

                    Console.WriteLine("Alert->"+i+": "+m1.alert_message + " " +"Message: "+ m1.notif_message);
                    string alert = m1.alert_message;
                    string type = m1.notif_message;
                    Pop(type, alert);

                }



            }

        }
```

I put the oher writelines in there to see how many times it'll print.

Comment: You are always setting i = 0.

Comment: Of course it never increments. You have int i = 0 inside the loop.

Comment: whoops..how did i miss that

Comment: fixed that part..any clues on why  Console.WriteLine("Alert->")...is being printed twice?

Comment: Well you have three embedded for each loops. Alert 1 Alert 2 Alert 3 Alert 1 Alert 2 Alert 3 makes sense if, for example, there are two strings in the values array, especially if nothing inside that loop will cause mm to generate with different messages for the second string in the values array.

Comment: That makes sense thanks..What about Pop()?

Comment: That I'm not certain about but here's my thoughts... It is probably either waiting until the code stops at which point it displays the last Pop() or it just keeps overriding the previous Pop() every time you call Pop(). Assuming that interior for each loop runs reasonably fast (as it should), you might never notice the overridden Pop() dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your i is declared inside the foreach.  it won't increment because you're setting it back to 0 every time.  place it before the foreach.